# New Relic Custom Info for Web Transaction

Tags: .net, newrelic

[image]

I'd like to add more information to the New Relic Web Transaction screen.  The current trace aggregates at the IIS level, and I was wondering if I can use the .Net API to add more custom detail to this transaction, like method level timings with PostSharp.  Is it possible to do this with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Relic .NET agent supports several ways to get more detailed insight into your transactions' performance.  For web transactions that use properly instantiated HttpObjects, you can add tracer factories to a custom instrumentation file:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-agent-custom-metrics

You might try adding some tracer factories for custom methods you want to instrument.

Another approach is to use the full .NET API:

https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api

Many of the methods currently only support web transactions but a few can be incorporated into a non-web app, like a standalone WCF service.  The API allows you to record timing metrics among other information, such as custom error reporting.

Yet another way to get more information on where your application spends its time is the new Thread Profiler feature, available in recent versions of the agent.  Thread Profiles give you a statistical look at the "hotspots" in your running application:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/applications-dashboards/thread-profiler